# How to dynamically show Bottom Tab Navigation with json data from server in React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I want to implement Bottom Tab Navigation.So I have done using react native Navigation.But,I need to load the data to the Bottom Tab Navigation that gets the data from json file from server.As of now,I have only implemented the static data and components.Can anyone guide me on how to implement this?

```
const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
});

const MoreStack = createStackNavigator({
  More: { screen: MoreScreens }
});

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeStack },
    Search: { screen: searchStack },
    Downloads: { screen: DownloadStack },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsStack },
    More: { screen: MoreStack }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

By design `react-navigation` does not support dynamic route, but you can instead make a higher order function that receive the json data you want as the parameter and them return the navigator as you want. The trade off is that the whole navigation stack will be reset.

Answer (score 0):

I had the best experience/results using [react-native-navigation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-navigation). It uses native components, so you get much better performance and feel. And you can set up bottom tab navigation easily.

Also, [this piece](https://medium.com/osedea/react-native-navigation-solutions-in-2018-6ff1dd7f6d20) is a really good summary of what's out there.